# How to cleanup this VM's checkpoint history

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019

My home server runs HyperV and I have a VM with a file share. I've been using Veeam to back it up, but after temporarily removing my file share VHDX, it prompted me to create a manual checkpoint. Veeam had 4 recovery checkpoints it failed to clean up from Novemeber 2022, and when I took the manual checkpoint, it reverted my data back to the very first checkpoint causing me data loss. I extracted a backup VHDX and attached it to the VM but Veeam refuses to backup now because the checkpoint history is a mess.

I'm trying to figure how to correct course on this. I'm taking a manual copy of the files on the VM before I do anything.

What's the best course of action here as I'm new to HyperV? I really just want the current state of the VM. My questions are:

- Since I previously had data loss when manually creating a checkpoint, I have little hope that doing a merge of the checkpoints will result in the current VM state staying the same, is that valid thinking?
- If I select the last checkpoint and do an export, will it export all attached VHDX files? Since this pretty much is the same as just deleting the checkpoints, any chance of the exported state not matching the actual current state?
- Is my best option to just rebuild the VM from scratch? I worry I spend 10-20 hours exporting or deleting the checkpoints, just for it to be the wrong data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current running state of your virtual machine is what you want, then deleting the entire snapshot tree will consolidate everything into that single image. Only the "revert" or "apply" actions cause deliberate data loss. The trick here is that the current running virtual machine must be exactly what you want.

An export action will create a consolidated set of the data files, whether you take it on one of the checkpoints or on the active virtual machine.